# Iterating an object's own properties in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have created a class that allows the resulting object to have arbitrary properties added to it. The class also has some predefined properties. In a method of the class I want to be able to iterate over all properties owned by the instance of the object.

Here is an example class definition:

```
import groovy.json.*

class Foo {
    private Map props = [:]

    String bar = "baz"
    def myNumber = 42

    void propertyMissing(String name, Object value) {
        this.props[name] = value
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        return this.props[name]
    }

    def toJsonString() {
        def outObject = [:]

        // I want to do something like this
        this.properties.each { k, v ->
            if (this.isOwnProperty(k) && k != 'props') {
                outObject[k] = v
            }
        }

        outObject = outObject + this.props

        return JsonOutput.toJson(outObject)
        // Should return a string like:
        // {"bar":"baz", "myNumber":42, "someDynamicProperty":"value"}
        //
        // This string should not contain the "class" and "metaClass"
        // properties.
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do what I am wanting to do?

**Edit:**
One of my goals is to not have to explicitly name my predefined properties in the `toJsonString` method. I want to be able to add new predefined properties at a later date without having to remember to update the `toJsonString` method.

**Edit (24 October 2011):**

The accepted answer gave me the information I needed. However, it still required me to name the properties I don't want included in the JSON string. Extending the answer a little bit solves this problem:

```
def outObject = Foo.declaredFields.findAll {
    // 'it' is a Field object returned by
    // http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()
    !it.synthetic &&
    it.getModifiers() != java.lang.reflect.Modifier.PRIVATE
}.collectEntries { v ->
    [ (v.name) : this[v.name] ]
}
```

For this to work, you must explicitly specify the modifiers for your class properties. That is `String bar = "baz"` in my example should be `public String bar = "baz"` in order for it to be included in the JSON string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's this possibility (assuming I've got the right end of the stick) ;-)

```
class Foo {
    private Map props = [:]

    String bar = "baz"
    def myNumber = 42

    void propertyMissing(String name, Object value) {
        this.props[name] = value
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        return this.props[name]
    }

    def toJsonString() {
        def outObject = Foo.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic && it.name != 'props' }.collectEntries { v ->
          [ (v.name):this[v.name] ]
        }
        outObject << props
        JsonOutput.toJson(outObject)
    }
}
```

If you don't have Groovy 1.7.9+, then the lines

```
        def outObject = Foo.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic && it.name != 'props' }.collectEntries { v ->
          [ (v.name):this[v.name] ]
        }
```

Should be replaced with:

```
        def outObject = Foo.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic && it.name != 'props' }.inject([:]) { m, v ->
          m << [ (v.name):this[v.name] ]
        }
```

And I believe it will behave the same; ie:  if I do this:

```
def f = new Foo()
f.tim = 'yates'
println f.toJsonString()
```

it prints out:

```
{"bar":"baz","myNumber":42,"tim":"yates"}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I am wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with this implementation, perhaps overriding [`getProperties`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.html#getProperties%28%29) to include your property map would be the easiest.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, the standard `fooInstance.properties()` method already includes the (not really) private map. I updated my question with more information on my goal.

Comment: @jsumners It includes the map, but as a map, rather than its entries as "top-level" properties. I'm saying to create a `getProperties` that doesn't include the map-as-map, but instead exposes the map's keys as property names, and values as those properties' values.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. However, when I `def getProperties(){ return this.props.keySet() }` then trying to set a dynamic property results in a "No such property" error. Also, I would still want to exclude inherited properties like "class" and "metaClass" without having to know them all ahead of time. This answer doesn't address that part of the question.

Comment: You can't *just* return this.props.keySet(), because then you'll miss the actual properties; that's why I said to *include* the property map's entries. The list of metaClass properties is short, and known, or you can explicitly remove super/meta class properties by filtering super.properties. But have you considered just using an ExpandoMetaClass? That was why I prefaced with "stick with this implementation", since Groovy already has a default way to represent a class for which properties aren't known until runtime.

Comment: I see now that I misread the documentation when I was trying to just return the keySet; it was a long day. However, I'm still having issues with this as now I cannot seem to create instances of groovy.lang.MetaProperty. The interpreter either looks for a MetaProperty method on my "Foo" object or cannot find "lang" on the "groovy" object (i.e. `groovy.lang.MetaProperty`). Let me be clear: I do not know Groovy. An actual example will benefit me greatly.

Comment: @jsumners Ah, not knowing it will matter ;) I can't right now, but if I have an opportunity this afternoon I'll play with it. (But consider an `ExpandoMetaClass` in the meantime--it may be what you're really looking for?)